# PHP Radio Button not sending value to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, radio-button

I'm trying to use a radio button to set the privileges of new admins and users when they are being added to a system I am making. The problem is that no matter what I choose the value for that field ends up as 'O' in the database. Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

(The connection is working fine so I won't add that in)
Here is the PHP for the database update:

```
$first_name = mysql_prep($_POST["first_name"]);
        $last_name = mysql_prep($_POST["last_name"]);
        $username = mysql_prep($_POST["username"]);
        $hashed_password = password_encrypt($_POST["password"]);
        $privileges = mysql_prep($_POST["privileges"]);

        $query = "INSERT INTO logins ( ";
        $query .= "first_name, last_name, username, privileges, hashed_password";
        $query .= ") VALUES ( ";
        $query .= "'{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$username}', '{$privileges}', '{$hashed_password}'";
        $query .= ")";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

And here is the html section with the radio buttons:

```
<p>Privileges:
            <div>
                User: <input type="radio" name="privileges" value="user" />
                <br />
                Admin: <input type="radio" name="privileges" value="admin" />
            </div>
        </p>
```

Comment: Plus, you may need to use [`multi_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) i.e.: `$result = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query);`

Comment: All the other inputs are working, it is just $privileges that always ends up as '0' in the database. But everything else works fine. I'm thinking I'm just calling the input wrong but haven't found a different example yet.

Comment: Oh wait, where does `mysql_prep` come from, is it an external class/function?

Comment: Yeah - 
'code' function mysql_prep($string){
  global $connection; 
  
  $escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
  return $escaped_string; 
 }

'code'

Comment: Is `$privileges` included in your function, if it needs to be added to it. I don't know how that function works, I'd have to read up on it.

Comment: The mysql_prep? No, but it doesn't contain any of my other inputs either.

Comment: And the column exists? with the correct field value?

Comment: Yup. I keep getting '0' for the value in it. So it is not even empty, which is the strange part. The radio buttons are supposed to send either "user" or "admin" but someone the value ends up being 0.

Comment: try running print_r($_POST); at the beginning of your processing script to see if the value is coming through correctly. this will help pinpoint the error. also, what is the datatype of your SQL field?

Comment: I "think" you may have an extra set of double quote in `$query .= "'{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$username}', '{$privileges}', '{$hashed_password}'";
        $query .= ")";` but I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Can you try it this way and see if it works? 
`$query = "INSERT INTO logins (first_name, last_name, username, privileges, hashed_password) 

VALUES ('{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$username}', '{$privileges}', '{$hashed_password}')";` @gv0029

Comment: @AndrewBrown - I'm using MySQL, and I'm having the form send to itself so how could I check with print_r()?

Fred-ii- - I just checked and I don't see an extra. However I am wondering if it would work if I called the radio button by ID but am not sure how I could do that with php and mysql since it could be either admin or user. Would I be able to add php in the middle of the query and dynamically insert the value depending if it's selected or not?

Comment: It worked but it still has privileges as '0'.

Comment: Can you make a screencapture of your table structure? Also, is the column named `privileges` and not `Privileges` with upper-case `P`? And what is it set to, `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, `INT` other? @gv0029 something is breaking it. `AUTO_INCREMENT` maybe? Hard to say without knowing exact structure.

Comment: Yeah, how do you want me to send it? And the column is named 'privileges' with a lower-case 'p'. And it is set to varchar since the value is (supposed to) going to be "admin" or "user".

Comment: even if you're having a page POST to itself you can add `print_r($_POST)` at the top. it won't show anything the first time you access the page, but when you submit the form with one of your radio buttons checked, it will display the post data. make sure it says something like $_POST['privileges'] => 'admin'. this will help eliminate one possibility of the problem.

Comment: Balls. I see it now. Yup there was a mistake in the db structure. Thanks Fred, I would have never thought to look there. You're a genius.

Comment: Aahhh yes!! So what was it exactly? @gv0029 curious

Comment: my next suggestion would be to `$privileges = mysql_prep($_POST["privileges"]); echo $privileges;` this will check if your mysql_prep function is doing something unexpected to your value.

Comment: What was the DB error in the structure? I'm curious to know (for my own knowledge). @gv0029

Comment: Wasn't set to varchar. Don't know how I misclicked that and never noticed lol. And didn't notice it until I was going through your list of suggestions. So thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. `Another Happy Ending` @gv0029 cheers. If you want an answer to close the question, let me know. Although not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your radio buttons with "[]"

```
<input type="radio" name="privileges[]" value="user" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to  Fred ii I realized that there was an error in the database structure. Since this column was never set to varchar it was returning '0'. I don't wish my stupidity on anyone but I hope if someone ever gets the same problem that this helps them!

Comment: You're welcome. And I think you can accept your own answer in a few days too, in order to close the question. Cheers